# What's special about /Applications on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm building a macOS binary to accompany a Chrome extension using the Chrome Native Messaging API. When the binary (unsigned, unnotarized) is in my Downloads folder, Chrome is not able to launch it. However, when I move the binary to `/Applications` (per https://stackoverflow.com/a/59710823/12581350), Chrome is able to launch it.

I was curious if anyone knows the reason why it's able to run from `/Applications` but not `~/Downloads`?

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because Mac OS creates application support folder to hold all the necessary data for  particular  application or software to run.
you cannot run an application or software if it's not in application folder, since  it cannot generate a folder in application support folder which is basically in the root of system folder.